# why pipenv install gives me Package installation failed... error

Tags: django, terminal, pip, pipenv

I want to run a django app so whenever i run `pipenv install` to install all the packages from my pipfile it gives me the error below

note :

- i'm running on windows
- cmake did nothing
- it doesn't change anything if pipenv shell is opened or closed
- i tried to delete pipenv manually and reinstall
- i tried to install and update wheel
  and thank you in advance

````
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (631114)...
An error occurred while installing boto3==1.26.86 --hash=sha256:7e8fc7bfef6481e48380d13e18a0a036413d126dc7eda37eadc1a052a3426323 --hash=sha256:e981703b76d2fb9274ce5cdda6ea382e29c9e7c65bc400c94c0a259b26f8914a! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing botocore==1.29.86 ; python_version >= '3.7' --hash=sha256:8a4afc6d540c01890e434b9a31fb1b17f8c759001e12c7ad7c49f55ea5805993 --hash=sha256:6083c649791559dd916c9ff7ac62486b391f6f9464d3cf6964582a489c866b11! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing charset-normalizer==3.1.0 ; python_full_version >= '3.7.0' --hash=sha256:4155b51ae05ed47199dc5b2a4e62abccb274cee6b01da5b895099b61b1982974 --hash=sha256:322102cdf1ab682ecc7d9b1c5eed4ec59657a65e1c146a0da342b78f4112db23 --hash=sha256:e89df2958e5159b811af9ff0f92614dabf4ff617c03a4c1c6ff53bf1c399e0e1 --hash=sha256:73dc03a6a7e30b7edc5b01b601e53e7fc924b04e1835e8e407c12c037e81adbd --hash=sha256:7381c66e0561c5757ffe616af869b916c8b4e42b367ab29fedc98481d1e74e14 --hash=sha256:34e0a2f9c370eb95597aae63bf85eb5e96826d81e3dcf88b8886012906f509b5 --hash=sha256:74db0052d985cf37fa111828d0dd230776ac99c740e1a758ad99094be4f1803d --hash=sha256:891cf9b48776b5c61c700b55a598621fdb7b1e301a550365571e9624f270c203 --hash=sha256:e1b25e3ad6c909f398df8921780d6a3d120d8c09466720226fc621605b6f92b1 --hash=sha256:fca62a8301b605b954ad2e9c3666f9d97f63872aa4efcae5492baca2056b74ab --hash=sha256:c36bcbc0d5174a80d6cccf43a0ecaca44e81d25be4b7f90f0ed7bcfbb5a00909 --hash=sha256:6734e606355834f13445b6adc38b53c0fd45f1a56a9ba06c2058f86893ae8017 --hash=sha256:3573d376454d956553c356df45bb824262c397c6e26ce43e8203c4c540ee0acb --hash=sha256:20064ead0717cf9a73a6d1e779b23d149b53daf971169289ed2ed43a71e8d3b0 --hash=sha256:78cacd03e79d009d95635e7d6ff12c21eb89b894c354bd2b2ed0b4763373693b --hash=sha256:9a3267620866c9d17b959a84dd0bd2d45719b817245e49371ead79ed4f710d19 --hash=sha256:d2686f91611f9e17f4548dbf050e75b079bbc2a82be565832bc8ea9047b61c8c --hash=sha256:d7fc3fca01da18fbabe4625d64bb612b533533ed10045a2ac3dd194bfa656b60 --hash=sha256:de5695a6f1d8340b12a5d6d4484290ee74d61e467c39ff03b39e30df62cf83a0 --hash=sha256:830d2948a5ec37c386d3170c483063798d7879037492540f10a475e3fd6f244b --hash=sha256:1435ae15108b1cb6fffbcea2af3d468683b7afed0169ad718451f8db5d1aff6f --hash=sha256:ea9f9c6034ea2d93d9147818f17c2a0860d41b71c38b9ce4d55f21b6f9165a11 --hash=sha256:75f2568b4189dda1c567339b48cba4ac7384accb9c2a7ed655cd86b04055c795 --hash=sha256:6f6c7a8a57e9405cad7485f4c9d3172ae486cfef1344b5ddd8e5239582d7355e --hash=sha256:22908891a380d50738e1f978667536f6c6b526a2064156203d418f4856d6e86a --hash=sha256:dd5653e67b149503c68c4018bf07e42eeed6b4e956b24c00ccdf93ac79cdff84 --hash=sha256:ac3775e3311661d4adace3697a52ac0bab17edd166087d493b52d4f4f553f9f0 --hash=sha256:628c985afb2c7d27a4800bfb609e03985aaecb42f955049957814e0491d4006d --hash=sha256:a04f86f41a8916fe45ac5024ec477f41f886b3c435da2d4e3d2709b22ab02af1 --hash=sha256:04afa6387e2b282cf78ff3dbce20f0cc071c12dc8f685bd40960cc68644cfea6 --hash=sha256:12d1a39aa6b8c6f6248bb54550efcc1c38ce0d8096a146638fd4738e42284448 --hash=sha256:3160a0fd9754aab7d47f95a6b63ab355388d890163eb03b2d2b87ab0a30cfa59 --hash=sha256:3d9098b479e78c85080c98e1e35ff40b4a31d8953102bb0fd7d1b6f8a2111a3d --hash=sha256:0be65ccf618c1e7ac9b849c315cc2e8a8751d9cfdaa43027d4f6624bd587ab7e --hash=sha256:ac0aa6cd53ab9a31d397f8303f92c42f534693528fafbdb997c82bae6e477ad9 --hash=sha256:b116502087ce8a6b7a5f1814568ccbd0e9f6cfd99948aa59b0e241dc57cf739f --hash=sha256:10c93628d7497c81686e8e5e557aafa78f230cd9e77dd0c40032ef90c18f2230! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing colorama==0.4.6 ; platform_system == 'Windows' --hash=sha256:4f1d9991f5acc0ca119f9d443620b77f9d6b33703e51011c16baf57afb285fc6 --hash=sha256:08695f5cb7ed6e0531a20572697297273c47b8cae5a63ffc6d6ed5c201be6e44! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django==4.2b1 --hash=sha256:33e3b3b80924dae3e6d4b5e697eaee724d5a35c1a430df44b1d72c802657992f --hash=sha256:9bf13063a882a9b0f7028c4cdc32ea36fe104491cd7720859117990933f9c589! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-admin==2.0.2 --hash=sha256:a92f9fb21f63edabb5db9030f36b62c6c16a0187183e7e7de4142aee4472b70f --hash=sha256:43c9f94ca5ad498789c0282691931c609c8e26db61aeb49ae8ad90d15b80cb75! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-excel-response2==3.0.5 --hash=sha256:ba908be16decbdc97b998bd20e596c27da78d23f97b533853c778c8c9c0974e3 --hash=sha256:4bbdd374cadd2d85723d5cd4b49822301141f7e4fef69616639cf3b7535e9ea5! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing django-six==1.0.5 --hash=sha256:9ad505d101ac3ce5a59d22693fcf77b4b19764020e0c7edfe939d220cafbf3a9 --hash=sha256:50816cf52e16814dff58eacd4883d9e5a43be37e53dcbd99323d1139ff89f73b! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing excel-base==1.0.4 --hash=sha256:3cdd3ef3366422eda12c7a72157053c8cbd06bcfe63a9280bc443ed21186372f --hash=sha256:5b3f2ead44a1b35ed3099e127fc3de9d6eb453bba9acc1058af215e21b4ee20c! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing isoweek==1.3.3 --hash=sha256:73f3f7bac443e05a3ab45c32a72048b0c4f26d53d81462ec4b142c7581d3ffe8 --hash=sha256:d3324c497d97f1534669de225ec877964222e4cc773a4a99063086f7a4e342b6! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0 ; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5' --hash=sha256:8314c9692a636c8eb3bda879b9f119e350e93223ae83e70e80c31675a0fdc1a6 --hash=sha256:af097bae1b616dde5c5744441e2ddc69e74dfdcb0c263129610d85b87445a59d! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing screen==1.0.1 --hash=sha256:29009e0306d005679cc43c8cd69856a046265433310c10e71920591de3c58fda --hash=sha256:aebfe90de7b8a646d4f3c2b214bd6ffa2ab12ed9d0b14c08620d9c7f7b8ee670! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing setuptools==67.5.1 ; python_version >= '3.7' --hash=sha256:1c39d42bda4cb89f7fdcad52b6762e3c309ec8f8715b27c684176b7d71283242 --hash=sha256:15136a251127da2d2e77ac7a1bc231eb504654f7e3346d93613a13f2e2787535! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing timeconvert==3.0.13 ; python_version >= '3.5' --hash=sha256:1f4ca99a7e88afe6e19d2d7578078555288055e362f0d170a1e35a8dadf38f03 --hash=sha256:9fa7f2eb43c17b8636171c98a8f599d9308b003395322f11cd4cdaba68cdc89a! Will try again.
An error occurred while installing tzlocal==4.2 ; python_version >= '3.6' --hash=sha256:89885494684c929d9191c57aa27502afc87a579be5cdd3225c77c463ea043745 --hash=sha256:ee5842fa3a795f023514ac2d801c4a81d1743bbe642e3940143326b3a00addd7! Will try again.
Installing initially failed dependencies...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting boto3==1.26.86
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached boto3-1.26.86-py3-none-any.whl (134 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting botocore==1.29.86
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached botocore-1.29.86-py3-none-any.whl (10.5 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting charset-normalizer==3.1.0
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (96 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting colorama==0.4.6
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting django==4.2b1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached Django-4.2b1-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting django-admin==2.0.2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached django_admin-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting django-excel-response2==3.0.5
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached django_excel_response2-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.8 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting django-six==1.0.5
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached django_six-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.7 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting excel-base==1.0.4
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached excel_base-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting isoweek==1.3.3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached isoweek-1.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.1 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached pytz_deprecation_shim-0.1.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting screen==1.0.1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached screen-1.0.1.tar.gz (8.6 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting setuptools==67.5.1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached setuptools-67.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting timeconvert==3.0.13
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached TimeConvert-3.0.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Collecting tzlocal==4.2
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Using cached tzlocal-4.2-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Building wheels for collected packages: screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for screen (setup.py): started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Building wheel for screen (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py clean for screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Failed to build screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Installing collected packages: screen, isoweek, excel-base, django-six, django-excel-response2, django-admin, tzlocal, timeconvert, setuptools, pytz-deprecation-shim, django, colorama, charset-normalizer, botocore, boto3
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py install for screen: started
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   Running setup.py install for screen: finished with status 'error'
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [15 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running bdist_wheel
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying screen\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying screen\old_str_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying screen\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       building 'screen.str_util' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/    
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ERROR: Failed building wheel for screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   × Running setup.py install for screen did not run successfully.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   │ exit code: 1
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   ╰─> [16 lines of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       C:\Users\Dream\.virtualenvs\movnw-backend-main-o0TZ4a8E\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:         warnings.warn(
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_py
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying screen\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying screen\old_str_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       copying screen\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       running build_ext
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       building 'screen.str_util' extension
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/    
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       [end of output]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: error: legacy-install-failure
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: × Encountered error while trying to install package.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ╰─> screen
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: hint: See above for output from the failure.
ERROR: Couldn't install package: [Requirement(_name='boto3', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='boto3', version='==1.26.86', req=Requirement.parse('boto3==1.26.86'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=boto3, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.26.86, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=boto3==1.26.86)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==1.26.86', index='pypi', editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:7e8fc7bfef6481e48380d13e18a0a036413d126dc7eda37eadc1a052a3426323', 'sha256:e981703b76d2fb9274ce5cdda6ea382e29c9e7c65bc400c94c0a259b26f8914a'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=boto3, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.26.86, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=boto3==1.26.86)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='botocore', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='botocore', version='==1.29.86', req=Requirement.parse('botocore==1.29.86; python_version >= "3.7"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=botocore, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.7', vcs=None, specifier===1.29.86, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=botocore==1.29.86)>), markers='python_version >= "3.7"', _specifiers='==1.29.86', 
index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:8a4afc6d540c01890e434b9a31fb1b17f8c759001e12c7ad7c49f55ea5805993', 'sha256:6083c649791559dd916c9ff7ac62486b391f6f9464d3cf6964582a489c866b11'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=botocore, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.7', vcs=None, specifier===1.29.86, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=botocore==1.29.86)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='charset-normalizer', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='charset-normalizer', version='==3.1.0', req=Requirement.parse('charset-normalizer==3.1.0; python_full_version >= "3.7.0"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=charset-normalizer, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_full_version >= '3.7.0', vcs=None, specifier===3.1.0, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=charset-normalizer==3.1.0)>), markers='python_full_version 
>= "3.7.0"', _specifiers='==3.1.0', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:4155b51ae05ed47199dc5b2a4e62abccb274cee6b01da5b895099b61b1982974', 'sha256:322102cdf1ab682ecc7d9b1c5eed4ec59657a65e1c146a0da342b78f4112db23', 'sha256:e89df2958e5159b811af9ff0f92614dabf4ff617c03a4c1c6ff53bf1c399e0e1', 'sha256:73dc03a6a7e30b7edc5b01b601e53e7fc924b04e1835e8e407c12c037e81adbd', 'sha256:7381c66e0561c5757ffe616af869b916c8b4e42b367ab29fedc98481d1e74e14', 'sha256:34e0a2f9c370eb95597aae63bf85eb5e96826d81e3dcf88b8886012906f509b5', 'sha256:74db0052d985cf37fa111828d0dd230776ac99c740e1a758ad99094be4f1803d', 'sha256:891cf9b48776b5c61c700b55a598621fdb7b1e301a550365571e9624f270c203', 'sha256:e1b25e3ad6c909f398df8921780d6a3d120d8c09466720226fc621605b6f92b1', 'sha256:fca62a8301b605b954ad2e9c3666f9d97f63872aa4efcae5492baca2056b74ab', 'sha256:c36bcbc0d5174a80d6cccf43a0ecaca44e81d25be4b7f90f0ed7bcfbb5a00909',  'sha256:6f6c7a8a57e9405cad7485f4c9d3172ae486cfef1344b5ddd8e5239582d7355e', 'sha256:22908891a380d50738e1f978667536f6c6b526a2064156203d418f4856d6e86a', 'sha256:dd5653e67b149503c68c4018bf07e42eeed6b4e956b24c00ccdf93ac79cdff84', 'sha256:ac3775e3311661d4adace3697a52ac0bab17edd166087d493b52d4f4f553f9f0', 'sha256:628c985afb2c7d27a4800bfb609e03985aaecb42f955049957814e0491d4006d', 'sha256:a04f86f41a8916fe45ac5024ec477f41f886b3c435da2d4e3d2709b22ab02af1', 'sha256:04afa6387e2b282cf78ff3dbce20f0cc071c12dc8f685bd40960cc68644cfea6', 'sha256:11d3bcb7be35e7b1bba2c23beedac81ee893ac9871d0ba79effc7fc01167db6c', 'sha256:12d1a39aa6b8c6f6248bb54550efcc1c38ce0d8096a146638fd4738e42284448', 'sha256:3160a0fd9754aab7d47f95a6b63ab355388d890163eb03b2d2b87ab0a30cfa59', 'sha256:3d9098b479e78c85080c98e1e35ff40b4a31d8953102bb0fd7d1b6f8a2111a3d', 'sha256:0be65ccf618c1e7ac9b849c315cc2e8a8751d9cfdaa43027d4f6624bd587ab7e', 'sha256:ac0aa6cd53ab9a31d397f8303f92c42f534693528fafbdb997c82bae6e477ad9', 'sha256:b116502087ce8a6b7a5f1814568ccbd0e9f6cfd99948aa59b0e241dc57cf739f', 'sha256:10c93628d7497c81686e8e5e557aafa78f230cd9e77dd0c40032ef90c18f2230'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, , markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===2.0.2, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=django-admin==2.0.2)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='django-excel-response2', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='django-excel-response2', version='==3.0.5', req=Requirement.parse('django-excel-response2==3.0.5'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=django-excel-response2, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===3.0.5, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=django-excel-response2==3.0.5)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==3.0.5', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:ba908be16decbdc97b998bd20e596c27da78d23f97b533853c778c8c9c0974e3', 'sha256:4bbdd374cadd2d85723d5cd4b49822301141f7e4fef69616639cf3b7535e9ea5'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=django-excel-response2, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===3.0.5, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=django-excel-response2==3.0.5)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='django-six', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='django-six', version='==1.0.5', req=Requirement.parse('django-six==1.0.5'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=django-six, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), 
markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.0.5, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=django-six==1.0.5)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==1.0.5', index=None, editable=False, 
hashes=frozenset({'sha256:9ad505d101ac3ce5a59d22693fcf77b4b19764020e0c7edfe939d220cafbf3a9', 'sha256:50816cf52e16814dff58eacd4883d9e5a43be37e53dcbd99323d1139ff89f73b'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, 
_line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=django-six, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.0.5, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=django-six==1.0.5)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='excel-base', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='excel-base', version='==1.0.4', req=Requirement.parse('excel-base==1.0.4'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=excel-base, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.0.4, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=excel-base==1.0.4)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==1.0.4', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:3cdd3ef3366422eda12c7a72157053c8cbd06bcfe63a9280bc443ed21186372f', 'sha256:5b3f2ead44a1b35ed3099e127fc3de9d6eb453bba9acc1058af215e21b4ee20c'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=excel-base, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.0.4, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=excel-base==1.0.4)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='isoweek', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='isoweek', version='==1.3.3', req=Requirement.parse('isoweek==1.3.3'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=isoweek, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.3.3, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=isoweek==1.3.3)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==1.3.3', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:73f3f7bac443e05a3ab45c32a72048b0c4f26d53d81462ec4b142c7581d3ffe8', 'sha256:d3324c497d97f1534669de225ec877964222e4cc773a4a99063086f7a4e342b6'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=isoweek, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.3.3, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=isoweek==1.3.3)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='pytz-deprecation-shim', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='pytz-deprecation-shim', version='==0.1.0.post0', req=Requirement.parse('pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0; python_version >= "2.7" and python_version not in "3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=pytz-deprecation-shim, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5', vcs=None, specifier===0.1.0.post0, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0)>), markers='python_version >= "2.7" and python_version not in "3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5"', _specifiers='==0.1.0.post0', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:8314c9692a636c8eb3bda879b9f119e350e93223ae83e70e80c31675a0fdc1a6', 'sha256:af097bae1b616dde5c5744441e2ddc69e74dfdcb0c263129610d85b87445a59d'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=pytz-deprecation-shim, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5', vcs=None, specifier===0.1.0.post0, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='screen', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='screen', version='==1.0.1', req=Requirement.parse('screen==1.0.1'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=screen, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.0.1, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=screen==1.0.1)>), markers=None, _specifiers='==1.0.1', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:29009e0306d005679cc43c8cd69856a046265433310c10e71920591de3c58fda', 'sha256:aebfe90de7b8a646d4f3c2b214bd6ffa2ab12ed9d0b14c08620d9c7f7b8ee670'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=screen, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=None, vcs=None, specifier===1.0.1, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=screen==1.0.1)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='setuptools', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='setuptools', version='==67.5.1', req=Requirement.parse('setuptools==67.5.1; python_version >= "3.7"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=setuptools, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.7', vcs=None, specifier===67.5.1, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=setuptools==67.5.1)>), markers='python_version >= "3.7"', _specifiers='==67.5.1', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:1c39d42bda4cb89f7fdcad52b6762e3c309ec8f8715b27c684176b7d71283242', 
'sha256:15136a251127da2d2e77ac7a1bc231eb504654f7e3346d93613a13f2e2787535'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=setuptools, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.7', vcs=None, specifier===67.5.1, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=setuptools==67.5.1)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='timeconvert', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='timeconvert', version='==3.0.13', req=Requirement.parse('timeconvert==3.0.13; python_version >= "3.5"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, 
name=timeconvert, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.5', vcs=None, specifier===3.0.13, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=timeconvert==3.0.13)>), markers='python_version >= "3.5"', _specifiers='==3.0.13', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:1f4ca99a7e88afe6e19d2d7578078555288055e362f0d170a1e35a8dadf38f03', 'sha256:9fa7f2eb43c17b8636171c98a8f599d9308b003395322f11cd4cdaba68cdc89a'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=timeconvert, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.5', vcs=None, specifier===3.0.13, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=timeconvert==3.0.13)>, _ireq=None), Requirement(_name='tzlocal', vcs=None, req=NamedRequirement(name='tzlocal', version='==4.2', req=Requirement.parse('tzlocal==4.2; python_version >= "3.6"'), extras=[], editable=False, _parsed_line=<Line (editable=False, name=tzlocal, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.6', vcs=None, specifier===4.2, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=tzlocal==4.2)>), markers='python_version >= "3.6"', _specifiers='==4.2', index=None, editable=False, hashes=frozenset({'sha256:89885494684c929d9191c57aa27502afc87a579be5cdd3225c77c463ea043745', 'sha256:ee5842fa3a795f023514ac2d801c4a81d1743bbe642e3940143326b3a00addd7'}), extras=(), abstract_dep=None, _line_instance=<Line (editable=False, name=tzlocal, path=None, uri=None, extras=(), markers=python_version >= '3.6', vcs=None, specifier===4.2, pyproject=None, pyproject_requires=None, pyproject_backend=None, ireq=tzlocal==4.2)>, _ireq=None)]
 Package installation failed...```
````

Answer (score 0):

This problem might stem from installing dependencies concurrently, instead of one-at-a-time. You may use `--sequential` flag such as:

```
pipenv install --sequential [PACKAGE_NAME] [MORE_PACKAGES]...
```

You may check out the [page](https://docs.pipenv.org/#cmdoption-pipenv-install-sequential) for more information.

If that doesn't work, then try the following if you didn't do it.
Lock your environment:

```
pipenv lock
```

Ignore the Pipfile for installation and use what’s in the Pipfile.lock:

```
pipenv install --ignore-pipfile
```

This will create the exact same environment you had, sub-dependencies and all.